# Versioned editing

Tags: postgis

Are there any solutions similar to Esri's Enterprise GeoDatabase versioned editing (and long transactions) solution for QGIS and PostGIS?

I've found QGIS plugins like pvVersion, gis_versioning, gitgig etc but all of them seem to no longer be actively developed.